# How to convert a higher resolution shapefile to the resolution of another shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-processing, resolution

I have a shapefile with ~110,000 grid cells which I want to convert into the same grid cell sizes as in another shapefile with ~27,000 grid cells? Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Details about the two shapefiles:

1. Higher resolution shapefile: ~110,000 rows in attribute table:

[image]

2. Lower resolution shapefile: ~27,000 rows in attribute table:

[image]

But both have the same country boundary. - India:

[image]

I basically want both to have the same number of rows which in a way means same resolution.

Comment: Shapefile is a vector format. It doesn't really have resolution or cell sizes. Please add a graphic showing what it is that you want done.

Comment: Added more details. Let me know if images are not clear. Thanks.

Comment: No, the same number of rows doesn't mean the same resolution. And a "graphic", among mapping people, generally means a map, showing both datasets, and how they overlay.

Comment: Try creating a grid with the "resolution" and origin of your finest layer. Then intersect this with your coarse layer, or join by location to get the coarse data to the grid cells

Comment: @BERA Thanks for the help. Can you please provide a stepwise process on how to go about it? I am pretty new to QGIS.

Comment: [Create Grid](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/creategrid.html), [Intersection](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html#intersection). Try it and come with a specific question if you get stuck